# Case insensitive matching python

Tags: python, string, case-sensitive

I want to match items from one list in another without worrying about case sensitivity.

```
mylist1 = ['fbH_q1ba8', 'fHh_Q1ba9', 'fbh_q1bA10','hoot']
mylist2 = ['FBH_q1ba8', 'trick','FBH_q1ba9', 'FBH_q1ba10','maj','joe','civic']
```

I was doing this before:

```
for item in mylist2:
    if item in mylist1:
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

But this fails because it is not case sensitive.

I am aware of re.match("TeSt", "Test", re.IGNORECASE) but how can I apply that to my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normalize the case with [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower):

```
for item in mylist2:
    print item.lower() in mylist1
```

The `in` containment operator already returns `True` or `False`, easiest just to print that:

```
>>> mylist1 = ['fbh_q1ba8', 'fhh_q1ba9', 'fbh_q1ba10','hoot']
>>> mylist2 = ['FBH_q1ba8', 'trick','FBH_q1ba9', 'FBH_q1ba10','maj','joe','civic']
>>> for item in mylist2:
...     print item.lower() in mylist1
... 
True
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

If `mylist1` contains mixed case values, you'll need to make the loop explicit; use a *generator expression* to produce lowercased values; testing against this ensures only as many elements are lowercased as needed to find a match:

```
for item in mylist2:
    print item.lower() in (element.lower() for element in mylist1)
```

Demo

```
>>> mylist1 = ['fbH_q1ba8', 'fHh_Q1ba9', 'fbh_q1bA10','hoot']
>>> for item in mylist2:
...     print item.lower() in (element.lower() for element in mylist1)
... 
True
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

Another approach is to use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
for item in mylist2:
    print any(item.lower() == element.lower() for element in mylist1)
```

`any()` also short-circuits; as soon as a `True` value has been found (a matching element is found), the generator expression iteration is stopped early. This does have to lowercase `item` each iteration, so is slightly less efficient.

Another demo:

```
>>> for item in mylist2:
...     print any(item.lower() == element.lower() for element in mylist1)
... 
True
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: I've changed 'mylist1', could you try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do:

```
for item in mylist2:
    if item.lower() in [j.lower() for j in mylist1]:
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

This uses `.lower()` to make the comparison which gives the desired result.

Comment: I've changed 'mylist1'. could you try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! much appreciated.

Comment: The list comprehension here creates a new list object every iteration over `mylist2`, lowercasing *all* values in `mylist1`. Even if only the first one needed to be lowercased to find a match. A generator expression in the same location would be more efficient as it would only be iterated over enough to find a match.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. But they dont account for mixed cases in both lists. Just in case you need that:

```
mylist1 = ['fbh_q1ba8', 'fbh_q1ba9', 'fbh_q1ba10','hoot']
mylist2 = ['FBH_q1ba8', 'trick','FBH_q1ba9', 'FBH_q1ba10','maj','joe','civic']

for item in mylist2:
    found = "false"
    for item2 in mylist1:
        if item.lower() == item2.lower():
            found = "true"
    print found
```

Comment: Yeah, it was just comparing each item to each item in a comparative search not overall. I edited it anyway to be an overall search

Comment: Your method now works, but is inefficient; like sshashank124, you should stop looping when you find a match. `for` also has an `else` clause you can make use of, instead of using a flag variable.

Comment: Interesting, i've never used an else with a for loop. I dont quite understand how that would work?

Comment: The `else` clause is executed if the `for` loop was *not* interrupted. So if you find a match, you `break`, and `else` is not executed. Don't find a match, the `for` loop finishes iterating, the `else` suite is executed.

Comment: I never knew about that thanks :) The way the clause appears I would expect the else clause to be executed if you DO break, not if you dont. Anyhow cheers everyday is a schoolday